# Parallelism question with adverbs

Tags: parallelism

I'm trying to understand the parallelism error in this sentence:
"The university's board of trustees, being worried over declining student enrollments and their failing to secure additional funding from the state, has formed a committee to determine what cuts need to be made to staff and programs."

I believe the parallelism error is this:
The board is worried over "declining student enrollments" and "their failing to secure". What exactly is the error? "declining student enrollments" is an adverb + adjective + noun structure right? Is "declining" an adverb here? Does "their failing to secure" need to be in that same adverb + adjective + noun structure too?

Can I change "their failing to secure" to "increasingly insecure funding"?

Is "declining" an adverb?

Comment: Is "declining" here a present partciple? gerund? What are those again?

Comment: I don't see any "parallelism error" here. I might prefer *concerned about* rather than *worried over*, and I'd probably use *failure* instead of *failing*, but the existing forms are perfectly okay. OP's suggested change would imho significantly alter/extend the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The board of trustees is worried about two *things* [nouns] - *declining* and *failing*.  Both  of those are gerunds, verb forms that can serve as nouns.

I don't think the lack of exact parallelism poses a serious problem. The only  parallelism gaff to my ears (and a minor one at that) is the introduction of the determiner *their* for only one of the things they worry about. I probably would say either

> The university's board of trustees, being worried over declining student enrollments and failing to secure ... [*their* omitted]

or

> The university's board of trustees, being worried over their declining student enrollments and their failing to secure ... [extra *their* added]

Both gerunds take objects, the first a true noun and the second an infinitive used like a noun. This does not seem problematic.

Your proposed alternative is not wrong, but it changes the focus from an active *failing* on their part to a vaguer lack of *funding*.

Comment: "declining" is a gerund here? It's a noun here?

Comment: @Cerberus I agree that the two *theirs* is a better form, but disagree that the worrier is the *subject* of the gerund. The enrollment declined and the [bid] to secure funding failed.

Comment: @bib: Ohh you're absolutely right. How could I have misread the sentence like that? I typed that comment in a hurry, but I wasn't in a hurry when I read the question. I don't know what to say. I will remove my comment.